# Material UI TextField type='search' not showing search icon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I'm new to react and have been using Material UI components. I want to display a simple SearchBar with search icon. This is what I have so far, however the clear icon is not displayed as I start typing.(using Chrome)

```
           <TextField
                type="search"
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="start">
                            <SearchIcon />
                        </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                }}
            />
```

What am I missing? How to restrict user input to only numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works for me, Please have a look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-rain-1dh1d) code sandbox

Below is my total implementation of the component

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        type="search"
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        InputProps={{
          startAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="start">
              <SearchIcon />
            </InputAdornment>
          )
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**PS: Clear icon only appears if the component in uncontrolled (i.e when you dont pass a `value` prop to it)**

Comment: Thanks, the same code I have. it indeed works in the sandbox but the behavior is different in my app though.

Comment: is there any property to restrict userinput to only numbers?

Comment: @SRaj, Can you update the question with whole implmentation or, can you create a sandbox with your exact implementation of the whole component

Comment: @SRaj yes there is `type="number"` attribute which you can use, But it is not possible to use both `search` & `number` at the same time, If you want it you can handle it in `onChange` handler, if you need i can help you with it

Comment: @SRaj, To add to my answer, the clear button only appears for uncontrolled components, if you are passing a value prop to it , clear button will not appear

Comment: Ah! makes sense, I'm passing value prop. Just to check if there was any way to assign a filter through property. I can add the logic to onChange, Thanks for yr help!